# How to redirect from model to dynamic url?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to redirect a url from Magento 2 model. Basically I created a payment gateway order inside Magneto model `initialize()` function and then want to redirect to a gateway's invoice page.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to redirect from a model? Redirects should happen in the controllers along with the rest of the logic. Models are for interacting with the database only.

I'm not sure what you mean by "payment gateway order", but if you're using a payment gateway then this logic will be available via a composer library install I should think and using dependancy injection to use the functionality within your controller. That's probably your best bet. If you have more info I might be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to redirect from model because was unable to override checkout controller. I thought it was possible to redirect from model with something like `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` function. It would very helpful if you can give some directions for overriding checkout controller.